# Wordpress User Roles inaccessible after updating Wordpress to version 4.9.7

Tags: database, wordpress, user-roles

After updating to the latest version of Wordpress 4.9.7, I now get these error messages at the top of my website:

**Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /srv/disk3/2206425/www/thailandpoolshop.com/wp-includes/class-wp-roles.php on line 278**

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /srv/disk3/2206425/www/thailandpoolshop.com/wp-includes/class-wp-roles.php on line 278**

The Wordpress Toolbar has also vanished, Wordpress Dashbaord cannot be accessed, users cannot log-in, checkout, or even view certain pages. Admins have no access.

I have replaced the entire Wordpress build, and also replaced with the previous versions 4.9.6 and 4.9.5 to see if the error would correct themselves but still they remain. I cannot login to the website as no user roles are available.
I have not edited this file at all. The automatic update happened overnight.

Can anyone provide any advice on how to fix this as I am receiving no reply from Wordpress, and many others having this same trouble on their forum also have no resolution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you happen to update Wordpress to a version that expects a higher PHP version?  What is the PHP version in use, and the new Wordpress version?

Comment: Wordpress version 4.9.7 (Latest stable version)
Servers PHP version 7.2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi Everyone,**

I managed to fix this! Since the **Wordpress 4.9.7 update** where many people were getting errors, downtime etc, I pinpointed the problem and the error sits inside your database. Firstly, backup your database. Always be safe than sorry!

Then, I disabled all my plugins via my hosting (Not within Wordpress as no access was available due to the user-role errors)

Now, using phpMyAdmin (Or you own equivalent) and clicking on your database, you want to open a new SQL Command. You can do this by clicking the SQL tab at the top.

Next you want to put this line of code as the SQL command which will select all from your wp_options table where the option name is equal to wp_user_roles:

```
select * from wp_options where option_name='wp_user_roles'
```

Now you will need to edit the option_value by double clicking in the box for that attribute, remove the current user roles that are messed up, and replacing with new roles that actually don't mess up your site! For me personally I used this:

```
a:8:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Administrator";s:12:"capabilities";a:184:{s:13:"switch_themes";b:1;s:11:"edit_themes";b:1;s:16:"activate_plugins";b:1;s:12:"edit_plugins";b:1;s:10:"edit_users";b:1;s:10:"edit_files";b:1;s:14:"manage_options";b:1;s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:6:"import";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:8:"level_10";b:1;s:7:"level_9";b:1;s:7:"level_8";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_users";b:1;s:12:"create_users";b:1;s:17:"unfiltered_upload";b:1;s:14:"edit_dashboard";b:1;s:14:"update_plugins";b:1;s:14:"delete_plugins";b:1;s:15:"install_plugins";b:1;s:13:"update_themes";b:1;s:14:"install_themes";b:1;s:11:"update_core";b:1;s:10:"list_users";b:1;s:12:"remove_users";b:1;s:13:"promote_users";b:1;s:18:"edit_theme_options";b:1;s:13:"delete_themes";b:1;s:6:"export";b:1;s:24:"manage_events_categories";b:1;s:12:"access_zopim";b:1;s:36:"wpml_manage_woocommerce_multilingual";b:1;s:37:"wpml_operate_woocommerce_multilingual";b:1;s:10:"loco_admin";b:1;s:7:"nextend";b:1;s:14:"nextend_config";b:1;s:19:"nextend_visual_edit";b:1;s:21:"nextend_visual_delete";b:1;s:11:"smartslider";b:1;s:18:"smartslider_config";b:1;s:16:"smartslider_edit";b:1;s:18:"smartslider_delete";b:1;s:15:"wpseo_bulk_edit";b:1;s:18:"manage_woocommerce";b:1;s:24:"view_woocommerce_reports";b:1;s:12:"edit_product";b:1;s:12:"read_product";b:1;s:14:"delete_product";b:1;s:13:"edit_products";b:1;s:20:"edit_others_products";b:1;s:16:"publish_products";b:1;s:21:"read_private_products";b:1;s:15:"delete_products";b:1;s:23:"delete_private_products";b:1;s:25:"delete_published_products";b:1;s:22:"delete_others_products";b:1;s:21:"edit_private_products";b:1;s:23:"edit_published_products";b:1;s:20:"manage_product_terms";b:1;s:18:"edit_product_terms";b:1;s:20:"delete_product_terms";b:1;s:20:"assign_product_terms";b:1;s:15:"edit_shop_order";b:1;s:15:"read_shop_order";b:1;s:17:"delete_shop_order";b:1;s:16:"edit_shop_orders";b:1;s:23:"edit_others_shop_orders";b:1;s:19:"publish_shop_orders";b:1;s:24:"read_private_shop_orders";b:1;s:18:"delete_shop_orders";b:1;s:26:"delete_private_shop_orders";b:1;s:28:"delete_published_shop_orders";b:1;s:25:"delete_others_shop_orders";b:1;s:24:"edit_private_shop_orders";b:1;s:26:"edit_published_shop_orders";b:1;s:23:"manage_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:21:"edit_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:23:"delete_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:23:"assign_shop_order_terms";b:1;s:16:"edit_shop_coupon";b:1;s:16:"read_shop_coupon";b:1;s:18:"delete_shop_coupon";b:1;s:17:"edit_shop_coupons";b:1;s:24:"edit_others_shop_coupons";b:1;s:20:"publish_shop_coupons";b:1;s:25:"read_private_shop_coupons";b:1;s:19:"delete_shop_coupons";b:1;s:27:"delete_private_shop_coupons";b:1;s:29:"delete_published_shop_coupons";b:1;s:26:"delete_others_shop_coupons";b:1;s:25:"edit_private_shop_coupons";b:1;s:27:"edit_published_shop_coupons";b:1;s:24:"manage_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;s:22:"edit_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;s:24:"delete_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;s:24:"assign_shop_coupon_terms";b:1;s:17:"edit_shop_webhook";b:1;s:17:"read_shop_webhook";b:1;s:19:"delete_shop_webhook";b:1;s:18:"edit_shop_webhooks";b:1;s:25:"edit_others_shop_webhooks";b:1;s:21:"publish_shop_webhooks";b:1;s:26:"read_private_shop_webhooks";b:1;s:20:"delete_shop_webhooks";b:1;s:28:"delete_private_shop_webhooks";b:1;s:30:"delete_published_shop_webhooks";b:1;s:27:"delete_others_shop_webhooks";b:1;s:26:"edit_private_shop_webhooks";b:1;s:28:"edit_published_shop_webhooks";b:1;s:25:"manage_shop_webhook_terms";b:1;s:23:"edit_shop_webhook_terms";b:1;s:25:"delete_shop_webhook_terms";b:1;s:25:"assign_shop_webhook_terms";b:1;s:20:"wpseo_manage_options";b:1;s:8:"backwpup";b:1;s:13:"backwpup_jobs";b:1;s:18:"backwpup_jobs_edit";b:1;s:19:"backwpup_jobs_start";b:1;s:16:"backwpup_backups";b:1;s:25:"backwpup_backups_download";b:1;s:23:"backwpup_backups_delete";b:1;s:13:"backwpup_logs";b:1;s:20:"backwpup_logs_delete";b:1;s:17:"backwpup_settings";b:1;s:22:"edit_klaviyo_shop_cart";b:1;s:22:"read_klaviyo_shop_cart";b:1;s:24:"delete_klaviyo_shop_cart";b:1;s:23:"edit_klaviyo_shop_carts";b:1;s:30:"edit_others_klaviyo_shop_carts";b:1;s:26:"publish_klaviyo_shop_carts";b:1;s:31:"read_private_klaviyo_shop_carts";b:1;s:25:"delete_klaviyo_shop_carts";b:1;s:33:"delete_private_klaviyo_shop_carts";b:1;s:35:"delete_published_klaviyo_shop_carts";b:1;s:32:"delete_others_klaviyo_shop_carts";b:1;s:31:"edit_private_klaviyo_shop_carts";b:1;s:33:"edit_published_klaviyo_shop_carts";b:1;s:30:"manage_klaviyo_shop_cart_terms";b:1;s:28:"edit_klaviyo_shop_cart_terms";b:1;s:30:"delete_klaviyo_shop_cart_terms";b:1;s:30:"assign_klaviyo_shop_cart_terms";b:1;s:18:"read_sales_project";b:1;s:27:"read_private_sales_projects";b:1;s:18:"edit_sales_project";b:1;s:19:"edit_sales_projects";b:1;s:26:"edit_others_sales_projects";b:1;s:29:"edit_published_sales_projects";b:1;s:22:"publish_sales_projects";b:1;s:28:"delete_others_sales_projects";b:1;s:29:"delete_private_sales_projects";b:1;s:31:"delete_published_sales_projects";b:1;s:16:"backwpup_restore";b:1;}}s:6:"editor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Editor";s:12:"capabilities";a:44:{s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:24:"manage_events_categories";b:1;s:7:"nextend";b:1;s:14:"nextend_config";b:1;s:19:"nextend_visual_edit";b:1;s:21:"nextend_visual_delete";b:1;s:11:"smartslider";b:1;s:18:"smartslider_config";b:1;s:16:"smartslider_edit";b:1;s:18:"smartslider_delete";b:1;s:15:"wpseo_bulk_edit";b:1;}}s:6:"author";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Author";s:12:"capabilities";a:11:{s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:24:"manage_events_categories";b:1;}}s:11:"contributor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:11:"Contributor";s:12:"capabilities";a:5:{s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;}}s:10:"subscriber";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Subscriber";s:12:"capabilities";a:2:{s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;}}s:10:"translator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Translator";s:12:"capabilities";a:2:{s:4:"read";b:1;s:10:"loco_admin";b:1;}}s:13:"wpseo_manager";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:11:"SEO Manager";s:12:"capabilities";a:46:{s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:24:"manage_events_categories";b:1;s:7:"nextend";b:1;s:14:"nextend_config";b:1;s:19:"nextend_visual_edit";b:1;s:21:"nextend_visual_delete";b:1;s:11:"smartslider";b:1;s:18:"smartslider_config";b:1;s:16:"smartslider_edit";b:1;s:18:"smartslider_delete";b:1;s:15:"wpseo_bulk_edit";b:1;s:28:"wpseo_edit_advanced_metadata";b:1;s:20:"wpseo_manage_options";b:1;}}s:12:"wpseo_editor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:10:"SEO Editor";s:12:"capabilities";a:45:{s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:24:"manage_events_categories";b:1;s:7:"nextend";b:1;s:14:"nextend_config";b:1;s:19:"nextend_visual_edit";b:1;s:21:"nextend_visual_delete";b:1;s:11:"smartslider";b:1;s:18:"smartslider_config";b:1;s:16:"smartslider_edit";b:1;s:18:"smartslider_delete";b:1;s:15:"wpseo_bulk_edit";b:1;s:28:"wpseo_edit_advanced_metadata";b:1;}}}
```

The reason it is so long of a user-role code is due to the amount of plugins that are being used on the website I have been working on, although this may differ for others websites. But feel free to give my code a try as it may fix yours also.

If not, then feel free to post a comment as I am still happy to help you resolve this, as I know how long it took me to resolve it myself!